# How does the Application Update work in XNA?

Tags: windows, xna, auto-update

I've made a game in XNA, and I keep updating it (locally), to fix or add stuff etc. I shared this game with a few people, and instead of re-downloading my game all the time, it would be very convenient if it could just update.
So my *question* is, what websites can I publish my game on? Would it have to be my own server, or would MediaFire work? 
How does it work when publishing the game to a website?

Comment: Have you thought about source control?

Comment: Definitely look into source control.  If the game is open source, you could look into github.  It is very easy to use and if you are using Visual Studio 2012, extremely easy to utilize.  https://github.com/blog/1420-github-for-windows-recent-improvements

Comment: If you do not wish your project to be open to the public, you can use [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) to create a private repository. Bitbucket allows use of both mercurial and git - so just take your pick!

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably referring to is updating only just changes made? If that is the case, then you are referring to a patch which is essentially finding the difference between your latest update and your previous update and giving it to the user. I am not aware of any software that does this automatically for you however - however pointing you in the right direction will hopefully help you find what you need.